# index with lodash times method

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I need to replicate a component "n" times. To do that I used the `lodash` method `times`. The problem is that I need an index as a key for the components generated and It doesn't look like it has one.

I have the following code:

```
export const MyComponent: React.FC<{times: number}> = ({ times }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {_.times(times, () => (
        //I need a key={index} in this div
         <div className="bg-white border-4 border-white md:rounded-md md:p-2 content-center my-4 shadow w-full">
         </div>
       ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

This will return the component that is inside *n times*.

I tried to do a method that returns the component and set an index with `useState`, but it goes in an infinite loop. I thought to put a big random number as a key so it is extremely difficult to get the same, but I don't like that solution. I'd like to use this method because it is clean.

So what do you think I could do to give a to the component?

Comment: Use a simple/standard loop... Why the need for a external dependencie?

Comment: @Marc I like it because it is cleaner. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's passed to you as a function parameter:

```
_.times(times, (index) => (blabla))
```

Comment: Where is this in the docs?

Comment: to be fair, I don't think it is. The doc only says that the second param of "times()" is a function, but I don't think it explicitly tells you what the function receives. Same goes for literally every lodash function param. If you look at map, flatMap or literally anything else, they only tell you that the second param is a function without defining what they send to the function itself. You just have to try it out and find out yourself

Comment: haha omg how is lodash so good but their docs are so terrible 